# Twitter Authentication in R

Tags: r, twitter

Trying to get Twitter authentication to work in R (for analyzing tweets), but RStudio does not respond to the PIN + get error messages.

I use Mac OS X 10.6.8 and RStudio Version 0.98.1091

Here's the code I'm using (incl. placeholders):

```
install.packages("twitteR")
library(twitteR)
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="my_folder/my_subfolder/http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem")


require(twitteR)
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey = "xxxx"
consumerSecret = "yyyyy"
Cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                     consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                     requestURL=requestURL,
                     accessURL=accessURL, 
                     authURL=authURL)
Cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl") )
```

I get this:
"To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=bWNevwJNJUPEzKLJwHQsK2uRLN4At5LO
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here: registerTwitterOAuth(Cred)
Error: Authorization Required"

When I enter the PIN in the console I only get this:

```
>1234567

[1] 1234567
```

I then try to run 
    registerTwitterOAuth(Cred), but get this in the console:

```
Error in registerTwitterOAuth(Cred) : 
  oauth has not completed its handshake
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong or how I can obtain authentication/authorization.

Very thankful for any help on this.

Comment: What if you follow the instructions on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR)?

Comment: Hmm, tried but get this:[1] "Using browser based authentication"
 Show Traceback
 
     Rerun with Debug
     Error in xor(is.null(url), is.null(handle)) : 
     could not find function "oauth_endpoints"

Comment: Did you also execute `install.packages(c("devtools", "rjson", "bit64", "httr"))`? Afaik `oauth_endpoints()` is part of the latest `httr` package.

Comment: Yes, I did. I wonder if it is because I have two accounts under Twitter apps. Maybe there are conflicts between the two different api keys and api secrets?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
library(httk)
library(httpuv)

#browser based authentication
consumer_key <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret<- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token=NULL,access_secret=NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following for Twitter authentication in Windows OS, and it works fine. Maybe it gives some direction!

```
library(RCurl)
library(twitteR)


options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "insert your consumer key here"
consumerSecret <- "insert your consumer secret here"
twitCred <-OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,consumerSecret=consumerSecret,requestURL=reqURL,accessURL=accessURL,authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this does it either. Same error message. I wonder if it's the fact that I am using RStudio instead of just R. Or that I'm using a Mac?

Comment: Well, using the above code, I could successfully complete my Twitter authentication in Windows XP and RStudio.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. At least I can continue using the RStudio. This is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out! The console won't let me copy the url after running the code, so I have to type the url with the unique token by hand. I wasn't aware of this. It's a little cumbersome, but at least it works. I'm running into other problems, which I read elsewhere on StackOverflow, might be a problem with Mac's operative system, so this might be linked to it as well. RStudio doesn't seem to jive to well with Mac.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the Application Settings of Twitter Developers you entered:

- Callback URL: http://127.0.0.1:1410
- Sign in with Twitter: Yes